# Use table name as variable

Tags: c#, .net, simple.data

I'm trying to use table name as variables

Base on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961471/retrive-data-with-simple-data-from-a-table-with-its-name-passed-in-as-a-variable)

I'm able to do it in some cases but in this one:

```
var usersId = db[tableNameLabel].All().Select(db[tableNameLabel].userid,
db[tableNameLabel].rating.Count().As("Count"));
```

I get the next error:

"The best overloaded method match for 'Simple.Data.DataStrategy.this[string]' has some invalid arguments"

**Update:**

**Fixed it.**

```
var usersId = db[tableNameLabel.Text].All().Select(db[tableNameLabel.Text].userid,
db[tableNameLabel.Text].rating.Count().As("Count"));
```

Needed tableNameLabel.Text.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to tag your question(s) with C# as well. Also, for us that isn't fluent in simple.data, which object is of type `DataStrategy` in this question?

Comment: I'm not fluent either. I just finish a simple app using this Simple.Data framework, but now I require to use dynamic tables. So I have problems with it.

Comment: Which object is of type DataStrategy in this question?

Comment: The following query is supposed to return a SimpleQuery [link](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/Commands/All.html) . However, when using variables for the table name, for some reason it returns DataStrategy. Just in this query specific though. The rest of them are simpler and working well.

Comment: OK, what type is `db` and what type is `tableNameLabel` ?

Comment: tableNameLabel is string.

Comment: db is Simple.Data.Database

Comment: And how sure are you that `tableNameLabel` is a string?

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Forgot tableNameLabel.text, you saved me alot of work

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `All()` here.  What is it doing?

Comment: it is fixed now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place in the code in the question where you use an indexer is in this expression:

```
db[tableNameLabel]
```

The error message:

> he best overloaded method match for 'Simple.Data.DataStrategy.this[string]' has some invalid arguments

is noting an indexer, `DataStrategy.this[string]`.

Clearly the compiler doesn't think that `tableNameLabel` is of type string, so check out that variable and see what it is.

Perhaps you meant to dereference a property off of that variable?